# discord.js no messages pass through the message collector filter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a music quiz where the bot plays a song and asks the question "What is the name of this song?", the user then is given a 30 second time period where it can enter the songs name or else it will say no one got the answer right in time. Now when I try executing this command and give the right answer the bot just ignores it and waits for the 30 seconds to run out and says that no one got it right in time.

```js
const filter = m => m.content.toLowerCase() === item.title.toLowerCase(); // the filter
interaction.reply({ content: "What is the name of this song?"})      
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 30000 }); // creates a collector with the filter and 30 second time period
collector.on('collect', m => { // this is the event that gets triggered if it gets collected
  console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
  interaction.followUp(`${m.author} got the correct answer!`)
  queue.skip()
});

collector.on('end', collected => { // this is the even that gets triggered when the time runs out
  console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
  interaction.followUp(`${collected.size} people got the right answer!`)
  queue.skip()
});
```

The item object is just a JSON file that contains the data of the current song: the artist(s), the URL and the title. So let's say for this example that this is the given information:

```
{
  "title": "Uptown Funk",
  "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPf0YbXqDm0",
  "singers": ["Mark Ronson", "Bruno Mars"]
},
```

Then even if the users says uptown funk, it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: What do you think this one does? `m.content.includes(item.title.toLowerCase() === item.title.toLowerCase())`. Especially this one: `item.title.toLowerCase() === item.title.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it, the way I was creating the collector was wrong changing it to this fixed it:

```
const collector = new MessageCollector(interaction.channel, filter, {time: 60000,});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your filter is not defined properly.

Currently, you're checking if the message you collected includes an `item.title` which is equal to the same `item.title`. This messes up the logic of your filter, and will return false.

Instead, you can do either of the two:

```
const filter = m => m.content.toLowerCase() === item.title.toLowerCase();
```

or

```
const filter = m => m.content.toLowerCase().includes(item.title.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: I changed it to that but it still hasn't fixed the issue